# 'LIKE' column name lookup using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I go about producing a query that will allow me to search my table to find any entries where the `data` field ends with the given value, like the following SQL would allow:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 'value' LIKE CONCAT('%', data)
```

Currently I can do the normal 'LIKE' syntax as follows:

```
return $query->where('data', 'LIKE', "%$value");
```

But it doesn't seem to support the reverse, where I am looking for the value in the `data` column ending with the `$value` input.

While I could use a raw query, I wanted to know if this was possible to do within Laravel's query builders so that I can ensure proper escaping, etc.

(Sorry for previous lack of info, pressed enter before I was finished and it posted question immediately)

Comment: Have you [looked at the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)? What have you tried? What are your models?

Comment: Pressed enter by accident while still making post - I have updated to add more information

Comment: `%$value` will do what you describe, right?  `$value` at the end of the field.

Comment: I think you're stuck with a `DB::raw` here.

Comment: @iCoders that matches `$value` anywhere in the field, which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: I want the reverse - trying to find where the $value ends with the data in the DB. Example `$value` = `Hello World` would match `World` in DB.

Comment: I think right here you will have to do it after query. Fetch all the results with the normal `LIKE` and then do the magic pos-query.